# how to run list of urls in linux using shell script

Tags: shell

I wanted to run list of urls which are stored in a text file, using some shell script. any help regarding the same would be of great help.

I would like the script for this program, so that when I click it. the program will run through a list of URLs (As in visit a website then replace that with another website, *visiting a list of URLs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the urls are in a file url_file.txt as separate lines, you could do:

```
for i in `cat url_file.txt`
do 
    wget $i 2>&1 >/dev/null
done
```

or instead of wget use lynx (or curl). For example:

```
lynx --dump $i 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

If by run a list of URLs you mean visit each one in turn you could use Perls [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.68/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) or [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.53/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm) modules (the latter should you need JavaScript support). [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) is an alternative, depending on exactly what you want to do.

Comment: ThanksI would like to hit the server with urls, and check the server log, no need of opening